# what does the word boundary's functionality in perl

Tags: regex, perl

$string = "Aa Aa 122";

```
 /\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b/
```

\b \b => does it search for duplicates of Aa Aa or it searches for that is not in [] ?

and what does the followin regex do,

```
/(.).*\1/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\b` matches a word boundary.  So the regular expression matches "Aa" but not "AaB" because there's no word boundary between the "a" and "B" in the second string; that is, they're part of the same word.

See The perl doc on [zero-width assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions).

The second one matches a string that contains two of the same character anywhere in it. It works because the `\1` matches whatever character was matched by the `(.)`, which matches any single character (that's `.`) and remembers it as `\1` (that's the `(`...`)`).  The `.*` means that anything can come in between them ("zero or more characters").

So "abra" matches (`\1` is "a"), as does "adder" (`\1` is "d", and the `.*` matches zero characters), but not "black".

Comment: The regex matches `Aab` because of `[a-z]*`

Answer (score 3):

The regex `/\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b/` searches for capitalized words containing only ASCII alphabetic characters. Examples:

```
Foo B Ba Bar
```

but not

```
bAr FOO foo BAR Føø BäÞ b
```

The `\b` is a zero-width assertion that only matches at *word boundaries*, where a “word character” `\w` and a non-word character are adjacent. It is equivalent to the look-arounds

```
(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)
```

The `\1` is a backref to a captured group, and matches the literal contents of that group. This regex allows us to match the string `foo` quoted by either double or single quotes:

```
/(["'])foo\1/  # "foo" and 'foo' but not "foo' or 'foo"
```

It matches either double or single quotes and remembers which. After the foo, exactly that character must occur again. Your regex is a more general form where `foo` can be anything, and the quoting character can be anything. This finds the first longest non-newline string that is enclosed by a character, e.g. in

```
:"':foo':"
```

this matches `:"':foo':` because it is the longest such string at the first position.